# Why Apache2 does not write logs?

Tags: 14.04, mysql, apache2.4, php7

Because I cannot find where Apache saves log files I tried even to reinstall LAMP, but no luck.

Ubunty 14.04, Apache 2.4, php 7.0.4, mysql 5.(5)

If I ssh to server, should I be able to get a path of this?:

```
$ echo $APACHE_LOG_PATH
```

I am getting a blank line!

Comment: It has, in my experience, always been in `/var/log/apache2`.

Comment: Yes, I thought it also, but got file not exists response. As it seams, even above echo $APACHE_LOG_PATH does not return anything logs are save but guarded inside folder you mention. I see now log files. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a default Ubuntu installation, the Apache configuration file, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` contains the following line to ensure that log files are written by default.

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
```

The `APACHE_LOG_DIR` environment variable is set when the Apache service startup script run the shell commands in `/etc/apache2/envvars`, which include this variable assignment:

```
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

Unless you’re running multiple instances of Apache, `SUFFIX` will be an empty string so the log file directory is, by default, configured to be`/var/log/apache2`.

Comment: I read about all that last night, and that is all OK. I am still confused why echo APACHE_LOG_DIR is not giving enything?

Comment: You'd need to source the `/etc/apache2/envvars` in order to set the environment variables.